# PostgreSQL how to filtering after where operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to do something like that

```
SELECT build.id as build_id, build.name, city.city_name as city, hours.day, hours.start, hours.end FROM Buildings AS build 
LEFT JOIN Cities city ON city.id=build.city_id 
JOIN OperatingHours hours ON hours.build_id=build.id 
WHERE city.id = 3
AND ( hours.day=4 AND ('20:00:00') BETWEEN hours.start AND hours.end)
AND ( hours.day=3 AND ('08:00:00') BETWEEN hours.start AND hours.end)
```

Is it way to do it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want buildings that are open at those two times, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT b.id as build_id, b.name, c.city_name as city
FROM Buildings b LEFT JOIN
     Cities c
     ON c.id = b.city_id JOIN
     OperatingHours h
     ON h.build_id = b.id 
WHERE city.id = 3
GROUP BY b.build_id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE h.day = 4 AND '20:00:00' BETWEEN h.start AND h.end) > 0 AND
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE h.day = 3 AND '08:00:00' BETWEEN h.start AND h.end) > 0;
```

If you want to include the hours and days in the results, then you need to aggregate them.  I would recommend `array_agg()`.

Comment: Yes, exactly what i need. Thanks!